# Java Swing: Showing tool tip in JTable based on text under mouse pointer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tooltip, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable where I display some string data formatted using html. I need to show a tool tip based on the text under the mouse pointer

[image]

On mouse over "Line1" and "Line2" I need to show different tool tips. Is there any way to achieve this or do I have to use a custom renderer to render each line with a cell and show tool tip based on that ?

Here's the sample code to create the table

```
package com.sample.table;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SampleTable {

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SampleTable");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.getContentPane().add(createTablePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static JPanel createTablePanel(){
    JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();

    JTable table = createTable();
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setRowHeight(45);
    addListener(table);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 120));

    tablePanel.add(scrollPane);

    return tablePanel;
}

private static void addListener(JTable table) {
    table.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() instanceof JTable){
                JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();

                table.setToolTipText("Some tooltip");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // do nothing

        }
    });

}

public static JTable createTable(){
    String[] columnNames = {"Column1", "Column2"};
    Object[][] data = {{"1", "<html>Line1<br/>Line2</html>"},
                        {"2", "<html>Line1<br/>Line2</html>"}};

    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

    return table;
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `getToolTipText(MouseEvent)` method of the component which your `TableCellRenderer` returns. If you are extending `DefaultTableCellRenderer` which extends `JLabel` and returns itself as renderer component, you can override it directly in your subclass.

You should be able to determine over which line the mouse pointer is using `MouseEvent#getPoint()`. See `JTextComponent#viewToModel` or `JTextArea#getLineOfOffset` (if you are using a `JTextArea` for rendering instead of a `JLabel`).

Comment: But I would still be able to get only the entire value in the cell (which is '<html>Line1<br/>Line2</html>') and not the actual line ?

Comment: No, you should be able to determine over which line it is using the point in the mouse event. See JTextComponent#viewToModel and JTextArea#getLineOfOffset
(oh, that would require you use a JTextArea for rendering instead of a JLabel)

Comment: I haven't had the time to try this out completely but using a JEditorPane might be more better than JTextArea as I am using html. I am accepting this answer as it is close enough :)

Comment: TableCellRenderer doesn't have getToolTipText how are you meant to override it?